# There is issue in Nuget package restore. All packages are not restored

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have used Nuget package restore in my project Solution in Visual Studio project. It restores some of the missing packages, but It does not override or restore `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props`.

Even I have this package when I browse in Nuget Solution window, as in image below. But again it gives me error when I build my project. error image attached below.[Error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKAw.png)
[NuGet Compiler package installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0uI0.png)

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks

Comment: You said "error image attached below" but there is literally no image attached.

Comment: when you click on blue links at end of paragraph, you'll be able to see images.thanks